# cordova-plugin-screen-orientation is not working with webview plugin in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using a plugin cordova-plugin-screen-orientation to lock screen orientation.
But it does not work because of cordova-plugin-wkwebview plugin.
I am using phonegap build to build.

I researched a lot about this issue but could not find any solution.

I'll really appreciate for any contribution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the below values in your `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value='portrait'></preference>
```

This value will lock the preference. You can also use `landscape` or `portrait` for the values

Comment: I found solution: http://ayyazzafar.com/lock-screen-orientation-portrait-landscape/